# Crystal Reports DateTime Formatting

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, formatting

I'd like to format a datetime in Crystal Reports to a include the day of week.

From:

> 19/06/2009

To:

> Friday, June 19, 2009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Crystal Reports XI Release 2 you can right click on the field and go to Format Field. On the "Date and Time" tab click the customize button. Under the Date Tab change the Date Type drop down to "Windows Default Long".

Comment: Is there anyway to implement this formatting in a formula? IE: I have two database fields that I want to combine into one Crystal Reports field.

Comment: I put another answer on here for this question to help other people with this same issue since (if people are like me) they generally don't really read the comments. If you want to do that you can just concatenate two functions similar to the second answer together in a formula field.

Answer (score 8):

If in a formula, you can use the following.

```
CSTR({?@end_dt}, "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy")
```

Comment: What if you still want to use the system format but in a formula. I'm trying to output a string for a minimum date, otherwise the date in the system date-only format. I don't want to hard code the order of month and day.

Answer (score 2):

If the DateTime is in field (not a formula) :

```
Right click on the field -> Format Editor
Date and Time tab
Select date/time formatting you desire (or click customize)
```

---

If the datetime is in a formula:

```
ToText({MyDate}, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
CSTR(Date({command.EntryDate}), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: won't this display "19/06/2009" instead of the requested "Friday, June 19, 2009"? (no CR on current computer to test atm)