# Crystal Report Formula for Date Separate

Tags: crystal-reports

Am New to Crystal Report 8.5

How to print the string value in a date Format?

Example:

dd/mm/yyyy

Where i have to type a formula in the crystal report?

Need Date Separator Formula for String value?
How to create a fromula in crystal report 8.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question...

To create a formula field in CR 8.5:

Insert Fields->Formula tab->New

in CR 10 and up:

go to the "Field Explorer", right click "Formula Fields", click "New".

or

Report->Formula Workshop->Formula Fields->New

Then you can drag the formula field onto the report.

Comment: +1 for explaining the part I didn't feel like explaining. :)

In Crystal 8.5 I think you add them from the Insert menu, but it's been a while so I could be wrong.

Comment: I noticed the OP had posted the same question twice. Yea, I don't remember much about 8.5 either. It is different though, will update answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new formula field to use in the report and use the CSTR or TOTEXT functions for formatting of the date.

You can use the help in the formula editor to look up the CSTR and TOTEXT functions to get the exact format that you want.

Here is a link for something similar. Look at the 2nd answer.
[Crystal Reports DateTime Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980877/crystal-reports-datetime-formatting/981730#981730)