# How to convert sql server datetime into operating system(windows) datetime format

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I want to select datetime field values as operating system datetime format.I have crystal report and its datetime shows as system defalt format.Various PC date formats can be different, so I want to convert datetime dynamically into system default format.
Is this possible to do?

```
Select AlarmedDateTime from AlarmMaster
```

[image]

The above image show my PC date time format but another user date time format may be deffer from my format, so I want to select AlarmedDateTime in users PC datetime format.

Comment: I want to make sure this is possible or not.

Comment: Every users use Windows in this scenario, But datetime format may be deffer.

Comment: what does AlarmedDateTime contain? which format

Comment: It contains date time values,(2016-10-31 05:54:31.000)

Comment: Is the format constant (In sample data it shows yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) also how are you checking what is the date format on the client PC?

Comment: this( yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) is the format of the server db record, I want funtion or any method to identify client PC data format from sql server and convert db records into that format,It is my question here.

Comment: Your application (in this case Crystal Reports) is supposed to assign the local datetime format to those fields. SQL Server doesn't have any way to know the regional settings of its clients.

Comment: Look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980877/crystal-reports-datetime-formatting

Comment: @MarcGuillot, Above link is not useful for my question ,But your your earliest comment answer is useful.I think this is not possible to do using sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to do using sql server.Need to use .net programming language to perform this activity.